# How do I remove duplicates from my scrapy spider result

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, pycharm

I am building a scraper for school,but I get all these duplicates in my output. Is there way in scrapy to remove duplicates from my output. My existing code is here below. The code is very simple because I'm just beginning with scrapers.

```
`import scrapy
from ..items import TrouwItem


class TelegraafSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Trouw'
    start_urls = [
        'www.website.nl'
    ]

    def parse(self, response,):

        items = TrouwItem()

        all_articles = response.css('#main-content')

        for articles in all_articles:
            straatrace = articles.xpath(path).extract()
            straatraces = articles.xpath(path).extract()


            items['straatraces'] = straatraces
            items['straatrace'] = straatrace

            yield items`
```

I haven't tried much because there wasn't much to find that could help me right now

Comment: you can create a dictionary or set class attribute that caches the results and check the cache to see if your item already exists prior to yielding it

Comment: You need to write an [item pipeline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#duplicates-filter).